# Storing Notifications in MongoDB document?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

```js
const Notification = Schema({
  read: Boolean
  receiver: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  }
  label: String
});

const User = Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String,
  notifications: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Notification"
  }]
});
```

Here I have a `Notification` schema and `User` schema and I want to know whether storing `Notification` ids in `User` document is the correct way or not. Should I store `User` id in `Notification` document given that `Notification`s are unbounded?

Comment: Why don't you just embed notifications directly to the user? Unless you want to share the notification with other users it would make sense.

Comment: Because `Notification`s are unbounded, I don't think embedding them into the user document would be a great move. They'll increase the size of `User` document unnecessarily.